# Null Pointer Exception in Fileupload process of Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am doing fileupload process in Struts2 application. When i display filename and contenttype in action class it showing null pointer exception.

I have included jar files and using the following codes.

In upload.jsp

```
<s:form action="saveBulkStores.action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <s:actionmessage name="message"/>
   <s:label value="File Name : *" />
   <s:file name="upload"  label="File" size="40"/>  
   <br> 
   <br> 
   <s:submit name="ADD" value="UPLOAD"/>
   <input type="button" onClick="cancelFunction()" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" tabindex="10"> 
</s:form>
```

In struts.xml

```
<action name="saveBulkStores" class="com.rewardz.action.FilesUploadAction" method="saveBulkStores">  
   <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
      <param name="maximumSize">52428800</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
   <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/> 
   <result name="input">/uploadfile.jsp</result>
   <result name="viewFile">/viewfile.jsp</result> 
   <result name="Reload">/uploadfile.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

In Action class:

```
private File file;
private String contentType;
private String filename;


public void setUpload(File file) {
   this.file = file;
}

public void setUploadContentType(String contentType) {
   this.contentType = contentType;
}

public void setUploadFileName(String filename) {
   this.filename = filename;
}

public String saveBulkStores() throws IOException{
   System.out.println("check Bulk upload file");  
   String filePath = request.getRealPath("/");
   System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);

   System.out.println("UPLOADFILECONTENT TYPE:"+contentType);
   System.out.println("UPLOADFILENAME:"+filename);
   System.out.println("UPLOADFILE:"+file);  

   System.out.println("**********************************");


   value = "viewFile";

   System.out.println("Forward Value:"+value);
   return value;
}
```

Output in Server.log:(Using GlassFish Server)

```
check Bulk upload file
C:\glassfish3_installer\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\My_Application\
UPLOADFILECONTENT TYPE:null
UPLOADFILENAME:null
UPLOADFILE:null
```

So anybody please help me to get the filename,filepath in uploading process of Struts2.

Comment: I can't see the issue... but I'll tell you what I don't like: I don't like you using a custom stack, go back to using the defaultStack (which has fileUpload already) and you should just be able to write saveBulkStores in the struts form (no .action postfix, but that is a trivial thing and does not really have anything to do with the issue).

Comment: I could post a complete working example using the struts2 conventions plugin if you don't figure it out.

Comment: I too had the same issue. But it gets resolved when `basicStack` is included after `fileUpload` as in your `struts.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Shiva the problem is with the  tag you are using in action class.

```
<s:file name="upload"  label="File" size="40" />
```

where upload property is not existing in your action class there is a property File file you use file instead of upload  so that will solve your problem

```
<s:file id="file" name="file"  />
```

Comment: I don't believe that's correct; it's the getters and setters that determine the property name--and in the OP's code they're named `uploadXxx`. Also, the `id` attribute is unnecessary. Your "correction" also disables the form field.